# Hide the Redshift schema to specific users or show only specific schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, controls, schema, amazon-redshift, admin

I want to show only specific schemas to the user in Redshift, hide all other schemas. The users should not see the other schemas and tables in schemas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible with Redshift. JDBC/ODBC protocol is exposing all available schemas **within the same database** to all uses, even if they don't have any permissions to them. AFAIK it's the same for Postgresql.

It sounds tempting to move some tables/schemas to a different database and expose that to users. Sadly databases in Redshift are isolated (you can't select from a different database).

So the only solution I see right now is to [`UNLOAD`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) the tables you want to expose, and then [`COPY`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) them into a new database.